# Process custom annotation in implementing class of an Resource interface

Tags: jax-rs, java-ee-6

I am trying to process a custom annotation on a class that implements an external interface that defines a Resource. The setup is the following:

A Resource interface, I can't modify it:

```
@Path("/v1")
public interface Resource {

    @GET
    @Path("/foo")
    Response foo();

}
```

An implementation that I can modify:

```
public class ResourceImpl implements Resource {

    @Override
    @CustomAnnotation // has Retention.RUNTIME
    public Response foo() {
        // foo logic
    }
}
```

I've implemented a filter to try and process the `@CustomAnnotation` on the overriden `foo()` method:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@Precedence("SECURITY")
public class CustomAnnotationInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        // check if the invoked resource method is annotated with @CustomAnnotation and do logic
    }
}
```

However, when I try to get the matched resource class from the `ResourceInfo` instance, I get the `Resource` interface, and when I get the matched method, I get the `foo()` method from the interface which is lacking the `@CustomAnnotation`. Is there any way around this?

I'm using RESTEasy as an implementation of JAX-RS.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an interceptor, where you can get hold of the actual resource (method and class) being called. The interceptor should be bound to your annotation using `@InterceptorBinding` (see [54.2.4 Binding Interceptors to Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/interceptors002.htm)).

```
// Interceptor
@Interceptor
@CustomAnnotation
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class CustomAnnotationInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object interceptCustomAnnotation(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        CustomAnnotation customAnnotation = null;
        
        // The actual method being called
        Method method = ctx.getMethod();
        if (method != null) {
            customAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
        }

        // ... do stuff with the annotation

        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

To get the instance of the class that implements your interface you could use `ctx.getMethod().getDeclaringClass()` or `ctx.getTarget().getClass().getSuperclass()`.